# Automatic Power Input Selection - Home Automation (mini)-Project

Tags: arduino, relay, home-automation

I live in a developing country where electricity is not available 24/7; however, to compensate for the power outage, I have 2 other incoming power lines from third-party generators.

The thing is, these generators aren't always on, and when they are, they're not necessarily simultaneous, however, at almost any given time, *at least* one of the 3 power lines is on, but I can only use one at a time.

Since I'm paying for all three, yet using only one, I thought it would be more efficient to use all hot lines in a predefined manner.
The existing electrical configuration in my house has 7 circuit breakers, each connected to a certain section of the house, so my plan is to have an Arduino choose the input line of each circuit breaker, thus distributing the loads between all available lines, automatically.

I designed a simple device to allow the Arduino to select the inputs:
[image: Auto-switching module]

Since I couldn't find a DP3T relay, I chose to cascade 2 DPDT relays to achieve the desired result.
V1, V2, and V3 are the power inputs.
IO_1 and IO_2 are digital outputs from the Arduino board (in fact I plan on connecting 2 shift registers in series, since I would need 14 - or more - pins)
Eventually, I would make 7 copies of this module to control each of the circuit breakers.

Depending on the state of IO_1 and IO_2, the *Load* would be connected to the +ve and -ve terminals of the selected power source.

The design seems viable on paper, however I'm not sure how this would apply in real life.

1. Are there any obvious flaws in the design that would require immediate modifications?
2. Are relays the way to go? Or do I need to consider other options to switch between lines?
   (The relays would have to stay in the NO or NC positions for hours at a time, until the status of incoming lines changes: for example, if one line is already hot, and another line becomes hot, the Arduino would be programmed to redistribute the loads and power on other sections in the house).
3. What relay contact ratings should I go for? Most of my breakers are rated at 10A, but I assume those breakers are more robust than the contacts of a relay, so should I go for like 15A DPDT relays?
4. Follow-up question: Do I have to account for resistive and inductive loads, or is it safe to assume that the existing 10A breaker rating has already accounted for load impedance?

I hope I was clear enough in my inquiry, and I apologize for the lengthy post, but this is my first time designing a module to handle high currents.
I may have more questions regarding the implementation of this module (using a PCB, wires...?), but I guess I'd rather have the previous questions answered first.
Thank you.

Comment: take out the LEDs from between the relay coil and the NPN transistor, and put the LED on the side of the IO_1/2 pin, AFTER the resistor or with it's own parallel resistor (probably better). Also you may be better off using an N-channel MOSFET rather than an NPN BJT. They are easier to drive and use as "power switches" in on/off control such as this relay setup.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll probably took a look at the theory of MOSFETs (I'm still a first year EE student, so I'm learning most of these things off YT tutorials).
I'm really considering affordability as well; I wouldn't want to pay $100+ to design something that might otherwise cost me less to buy from manufacturers.

Comment: MOSFETs may cost only a small amount more than transistors - your real cost will come from the arduino and from the relays.